# Removing some Mail Headers in Google App Engine Mail Services

Tags: google-app-engine

Currently need to resolve this issue, Looking for some suggestions, the issue is i need to remove some Headers provided by Mail Services in Google App Engine to use in accordance with Sprint Mail. So if there any possible ways ,Post your valuable suggestions.

Note: Currently i am using another SMTP services to provide Temprorary Solution. Need to Migrate it to GAE.

Comment: Which headers? Why do you need to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Just any possible header to remove from Mail service of gae, for example return-path: or anything , if can be removed.

One More is that gae smtp allows to remove any particular Header.